# Importing manual changes to terraform state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-state

I was trying to change the EC2 type using Terraform but the Terraform plan just wouldn't recognise the EC2 SKU change, so I went ahead and manually changed the size via the Amazon console.

I am using a remote state file, now I would like to sync the manual change that I made into the state file, is there a way that I could do so?

Comment: What does `terraform plan` say?

Comment: It said "no changes  Your infrastructure matches the configuration" pre and post the manual change.